# How to disable ripple effect on password toggle button of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I use TextInputLayout to show password toggle button. It is working but the ripple effect is behind the background of the EditText (I use drawable background for the EditText). How can I disable the ripple effect of the password button or bring the ripple in front of the EditText background? Here the recorded video that demonstrated the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1TSE.jpg.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_edit"
                    android:hint="••••••"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="18dp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using `android:background="@drawable/bg_edit"` in your `EditText`?

Comment: Post the layout you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Remove android:background and try once

Comment: I need the background for the look of the form so I can't remove it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not brilliant solution, but it work for me.
materialVersion: 1.1.0

Koltin:

```
textInputLayout.apply {
        findViewById<View>(R.id.text_input_end_icon).setBackgroundColor(
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.transparent, theme)
        )
    }
```

`R.id.text_input_end_icon` was find via Layout Inspector

Comment: Just tested with Xamarin.Android doing necessary syntax modifications and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result removing the `android:background="@drawable/bg_edit"` in your `TextInputEditText` and using an [OutlinedBox style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#outlined-box):

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:hint="••••••"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/....."
        ..>

           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="18dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Note: `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` is deprecated. Just add [**`app:endIconMode="password_toggle"`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#password-redaction).

Comment: I have tried OutlinedBox style, but it doesn't work out of the box. Here is the look before focus https://imgur.com/nhlGIeB and here the look after focus on the edittext https://imgur.com/nUVTMCC.

Comment: @BagusAjiSantoso It is not clear. You have to remove the background in the TextInputEditText.

Comment: Yeah, I have removed the background, but the OutlinedBox looks like it didn't align well. I have no other attributes except style, constraints, and width/height.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way, create a new theme for password toggle is shown below. Parent theme is your main(App) theme.

```
<style name="PasswordToggleTransparent" parent="NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#0000</item>
</style>
```

and apply this theme to your **TextInputLayout**:

```js
android:theme="@style/PasswordToggleTransparent"
```

Comment: This works, somehow it only works when applied as android:theme instead of a style